Is $C_i$ monotonically decreasing, and does it possess an analytical solution?
Let $$\alpha_i = \frac{b+i}{b+i^a}, 0<a\leq 1$$ and $$\alpha_t^i = \alpha_i \prod_{j={i+1}}^{t}(1-\alpha_j)$$ I aimed to derive the analytical expression for $$C_i = \sum_{t=i}^{\infty}\alpha_t^i$$ According to Lemma 4.1 from https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03765, we obtain that $C_i = \frac{b+1}{b}, \forall i$. However, this lemma does not extend to the case where $a < 1$. Consequently, I pose the following questions:

Is it possible to obtain the analytical value of $C_i$?
Does the inequality $C_{i+1} \leq C_{i}$ hold true for all $0<a\leq1$?

I have executed code to validate the second question, which empirical results suggest is correct; however, I have been unable to provide a formal proof. To my best knowledge, the relation between $C_{i+1}$ and $C_i$ is:
$$
C_{i+1} = \frac{b+i^a}{(i+1)^a - 1}C_i - \frac{b+1}{(i+1)^a - 1}
$$
I am grateful to anyone who can shed light on these questions and contribute to a deeper understanding of this mathematical problem. Thank you for your insights and assistance.
